# Plugin to extend import make project into Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing using a make based c++ framework and using a custom toolchain.

I know how to setup the include paths so eclipse can discover the libraries and headers of the framework, also properly index and verify the code.

But I'm needing to do this for every project, every time.

So I would like to create a simple plugin so it can import my projects into the workspace using the existent make file import wizard. Then it will set to the imported project the toolchain's and framework associated libraries and include files automatically.

could someone point me to any tutorial or document that would help with that challenge?

Comment: Depending on the toolchain, you may be able to accomplish this without writing a plugin. In `Project Properties | C/C++ General | Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. | Providers`, see if you can customize the `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` provider to pick up your toolchain's built-in includes and macro definitions.

Comment: As for the includes for your framework, presumably you are specifying those in your makefile. CDT can pick those up by parsing the output of your build command. Enable the `CDT GCC Build Output Parser` provider in the same place, and see if you can get it to recognize your toolchain's compiler by adjusting the `Compiler command pattern`.

Comment: @HighCommander4, thanks. but I'm already able to customize the configuration using the ways you have pointed. But the problem is that I (and my colleagues) need to do this for every project on different machines.
I've found the source code of org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core and org.eclipse.cdt.make.core. I will research them in my freetime.